# tkinter entry boxes - optional input

Tags: python, tkinter, filtering

I have four entry boxes in my gui and whatever information I put in there, .get() works as it should. The problem starts further below on the conditions. The reason for these entry boxes is the filtering of a dataframe

The first condition has several conditions within with OR (|). These conditions are packed as "conditionORall", the other conditions have one condition at the time. The goal is to filter a dataframe based on user input. With this code, this works only if I fill out all four entry boxes as the conditions are with (&). I want to be able to for e.g. search for all data prior the end date of 20220101. An the result should be all data upon the given date, without entering more boxes. Right now it results in a blank sheet if I leave one entry box blank.

Is there a way to set these entry boxes somehow as default=True so it considers all information if left blank? for e.g. I also tried using (len(condition6) > 0 in order to create a final condition dynamically. But it just did not work. It is probably a very easy question but I couldn't figure it out in the past 6hrs. Thank you for you help.

---

```
namesec = namesec_execII.get().strip()
symbol = namesec_execII.get().strip()
start = start_execII.get().strip()
end = end_execII.get().strip()
segment = segment_execII.get().strip()



inputfile = 'testfile.pkl'
df = pd.read_pickle(inputfile)
 


conditionORall = ((df['namesec'] == namesec) | (df['localMnemonic'] == symbol) | (df['securityShortName'].str.contains(symbol)))
condition6 = (df['SegmentID'] == segment)
condition7 = (df['TradeDate'] >= start)
condition8 = (df['TradeDate'] <= end)



df = df.loc[(conditionORall) & (condition6) & (condition7) & (condition8)]        

df.to_excel('result.xlsx', index=False)




namesec_execII=StringVar()
namesec_entry_execII = Entry(my_frame10,textvariable = namesec_execII, bg='white', font=('Helvetica',12, 'normal'))

start_execII=StringVar()
start_entry = Entry(my_frame10,textvariable = start_execII, bg='white', font=('Helvetica',12, 'normal'))

end_execII=StringVar()
end_entry = Entry(my_frame10,textvariable = end_execII, bg='white', font=('Helvetica',12, 'normal'))

segment_execII=StringVar()
segment_entry = Entry(my_frame10,textvariable = segment_execII, bg='white', font=('Helvetica',12, 'normal'))
```

Comment: Try adding ` | segment == "" ` to the segment condition.  Does this work?

Comment: It still forces me to fill every entry box. I also extended the OR | on the other conditions (dates) too. condition6 = ((df['SegmentID'] == segment) | (df['SegmentID'] == " "))

Comment: Please provide a [*complete* minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Currently, the overall structure of your code is not clear. (Whether the given code lines are part of a *function* or in the *global scope*)

Comment: Correct, the given code is part of a function. I simplified the code without mainloop. The full code running creates a gui with approx 70-80 functions. One of them is the above mentioned code which creates four entry boxes. Once informatione has been entered, a button (not included in code) collects all the information .get(). This part works fine. Then the code reads a dataframe (with pandas) and based on the user entry it should filter out the information. My goal is that only entered information in the boxes should be considered. The blank ones should be ignored as filtering wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a filter *optional*, you can consider the default return value to be `True` unless the filter is *non-empty*. This can be done in the following way:

```py
conditionORall = ((df['namesec'] == namesec) | (df['localMnemonic'] == symbol) | (df['securityShortName'].str.contains(symbol)))
condition6 = (df['SegmentID'] == segment) if segment != "" else True
condition7 = (df['TradeDate'] >= start) if start != "" else True
condition8 = (df['TradeDate'] <= end) if end != "" else True

df = df.loc[(conditionORall) & (condition6) & (condition7) & (condition8)]
```

You can use the same approach to add further optional filters in the future.